# How does Gunicorn load and execute app?

Tags: python, gunicorn

Let's say I'm using the sample app from Gunicorn website:

```
def app(environ, start_response):
    data = b"Hello, World!\n"
    start_response("200 OK", [
        ("Content-Type", "text/plain"),
        ("Content-Length", str(len(data)))
    ])
    return iter([data])
```

Then I run the server:

```
gunicorn -w 4 myapp:app
```

Do I understand it correctly that each worker represents a separate Python process with the loaded module `myapp`? If so, if I had a global variable in this module, I could safely have 4 distinct states (although this is a bad idea, just as an example).

I ran a simple experiment with a slightly modified application above:

```
import os
import string
import random

global_list = []


def app(environ, start_response):
    random_char = random.sample(string.ascii_uppercase, 1).pop()
    global_list.append(random_char)

    s = ("PID=%s %s" % (os.getpid(), global_list)).encode('ascii')
    data = bytes(s)
    start_response("200 OK", [
        ("Content-Type", "text/plain"),
        ("Content-Length", str(len(data)))
    ])
    return iter([data])
```

And here's what I got while making requests one by one:

- PID=9 ['A']
- PID=8 ['Y']
- PID=9 ['A', 'R']
- **PID=7 ['I', 'X', 'I']**
- ...

Why does the last output has three items and not one if the worker with PID 7 was set off for the first time? Can someone enlighten me please? I didn't find anything in Gunicorn docs.

Thank you.

**PS:** OK, I figured it out. Since I was making the requests from browser, it silently requested for `/favicon.ico`, hence three unexpected requests were made. After I tried curl, it worked just fine.

Now the only question is about one Python process per worker. Is it really so?

Answer (score 0):

> Do I understand it correctly that each worker represents a separate Python process with the loaded module myapp?

Yes, exactly. From the [Gunicorn docs](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#workers):

> workers:
>   The number of worker processes for handling requests.

(Note that Gunicorn will only load your app once, and then fork the requested number of workers, so your app isn't actually "loaded" N times.)

> If so, if I had a global variable in this module, I could safely have 4 distinct states (although this is a bad idea, just as an example).

Yes, each process will have its own state.